# Как в YII сделать несколько SQL запросов за одно заполнение формы

Tags: php, yii, mysql

Всем привет. Есть две таблицы: Законы и Группы. Связь многие ко многим - в одной группе может быть несколько законов и один закон может состоять в нескольких группах. Дело в том, что когда создаю законы есть необходимость закон поместить сразу в несколько групп одновременно. Для этого создаю под законом несколько полей равное количеству групп, чтобы заполнить туда названия (на самом деле на сервер кончено же будет уходить id группы) групп. Проблема в том, что нельзя заполнить одно поле таблицы одновременно. Как в таком случае быть? Может в YII это можно решить стандартными средствами?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону табличного ввода. Вы сможете создать форму "закон" и под ней несколько форм "группа".

[Работа с формами: Табличный ввод](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/form.table)

Answer (score 0):

если связь многие-ко-многим. я вот делал [так](http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2015/03/yii-yii-for-dummies-chtmlcheckboxlist.html)

там подробная инструкция. если вкратце, то все идет с помощью relations
и в результате получим что-то вроде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]